# Добавить массив данных в базу

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста как с поля etaj добавить массив данных т.е 1,2,3,4. И будет ли так искать по диапазону? или лучше создать отдельные поля от и до?

```
  <?php
  // Соединение с базой
  include ('config.php');

    //Если переменная name передана
    if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
      //Если это запрос на обновление, то обновляем
      if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) {
          $sql = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `users` SET `name` = '{$_POST['name']}',`category` = '{$_POST['category']}',`region` = '{$_POST['region']}',`money` = '{$_POST['money']}',`do_money` = '{$_POST['do_money']}',`area` = '{$_POST['area']}',`do_area` = '{$_POST['do_area']}',`etaj` = '{$_POST['etaj']}',`tip-doma` = '{$_POST['tip-doma']}',`phone` = '{$_POST['phone']}',`premich` = '{$_POST['premich']}',`time` = '{$_POST['time']}' WHERE `id`={$_GET['red_id']}");
        } else {
          //Иначе вставляем данные, подставляя их в запрос
          $sql = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `category`, `region`, `money`, `do_money`, `area`, `do_area`, `etaj`, `tip-doma`, `phone`, `premich`, `time`) VALUES ('{$_POST['name']}', '{$_POST['category']}', '{$_POST['region']}', '{$_POST['money']}', '{$_POST['do_money']}', '{$_POST['area']}', '{$_POST['do_area']}', '{$_POST['etaj']}', '{$_POST['tip-doma']}', '{$_POST['phone']}', '{$_POST['premich']}', '{$_POST['time']}')");
        }

      //Если вставка прошла успешно
      if ($sql) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> ';
        echo '$.jGrowl("Успешно!", { 
            theme: "green"});';
      } else {
        echo '$.jGrowl("Произошла ошибка: ' . mysqli_error($link) . '", { 
            theme: "red"
        });';
      }
      echo '</script>';
    }

    if (isset($_GET['del_id'])) { //проверяем, есть ли переменная
      //удаляем строку из таблицы
      $sql = mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id` = {$_GET['del_id']}");
      if ($sql) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> ';
        echo '$.jGrowl("Пользователь удален!", { 
            theme: "green"});';
      } else {
        echo '$.jGrowl("Произошла ошибка: ' . mysqli_error($link) . '", { 
            theme: "red"
        });';
      }
      echo '</script>';
    }

    //Если передана переменная red_id, то надо обновлять данные. Для начала достанем их из БД
    if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) {
      $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`={$_GET['red_id']}");
      $product = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    }
    $dt=date('d-m-Y');
    if (isset($_GET['red_id'])) {
        $edit = 'Изменение клиента';
        }else {
            $add = 'Добавление клиента в базу';
          }

  ?>
```

Comment: `$query = "INSERT INTO table(data) VALUES ('{json_encode($dataArray)}')"` - просто делаем json строку с массива, но для поиска это всё усложнит немного

Comment: Если может быть только интервал - то и хранить надо _от_ и _до_. Перечислять данные не стоит. поиск в наборе значений в одном поле невозможно выполнить оптимально (по индексу), а вот `X between e_from and e_to` гораздо лучше поддается оптимизации

Comment: добавил два поля от и до, но как осуществить поиск?

Comment: `WHERE @value BETWEEN field_from AND field_to`.